Is it possible to make an AHK script that takes a spacebar hold and make it a tap?
How can I make it so when I hold the spacebar it acts like one normal press?
Here is my code:
#InputLevel, 10  ;set send level for the following code to 10
$Space::
#InputLevel  ;set it back to default value of 0 for any remaining code
now := A_TickCount
while GetKeyState("Space", "P") ; to find out whether space-bar is held 
    if (A_TickCount-now > 180) ; this time is tested on asker's computer
    {
        SendInput {Space Down}
        SendInput {Space Up}
        return
    }

SendInput {Space} ; if key detected to be tapped, send space as per normal   
return

Got it form some other forums, but the current problem is it just repeats pressing the space key over and over

Ok guys I fixed it. I added one line to fix it.
#InputLevel, 10  ;set send level for the following code to 10
$Space::
#InputLevel  ;set it back to default value of 0 for any remaining code
now := A_TickCount
while GetKeyState("Space", "P") ; to find out whether space-bar is held 
    if (A_TickCount-now > 180) ; this time is tested on asker's computer
    {
        SendInput {Space Down}
        SendInput {Space Up}
        KeyWait, Space
        return
    }

SendInput {Space} ; if key detected to be tapped, send space as per normal   
return

most of it is from another post found here at the first answer: Autohotkey script to send space when tapped and shift when held. It is affecting other mappings
